# Does this sentence have two meanings?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

A couple of math teacher colleagues of mine are discussing two interpretations of the following sentence:

> A number will give the answer 6 when it has been doubled.

The intended interpretation was that "it" refers to "a number" (so that the required number is 3). The alternative interpretation is that "it" also could refer to "6" (so that the number is 12).

To me the sentence structure seems lacking for other reasons (how can a number "give an answer" at all), but I would appreciate your input on whether or not the second interpretation could be considered correct, as this is the way several students seem to have understood it.

Comment: Personally, only the first interpretation makes any sense to me.  I agree that it feels wrong to say that "a number will give the answer" - it's the sum, or the function that gives an answer.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: About "giving the answer", this could be considered correct if you consider the calculation as a **function**. In that case, an input parameter "gives" (leads to) the output parameter. _"In a doubling function, [inputting] 6 will return 12"_

Comment: 'When it has been doubled' defaults to referencing 'a number' here; the proposed alternative reading would always be conveyed differently. There used to be a warning on A-Level maths papers: 'Unnecessarily convoluted, complex or rambling answers will be marked down even if essentially correct.' The same principle applies to the interpretation and writing of English; pragmatics is as important as syntax.

Comment: @Flater I see what you mean, but it's still not a wording I would choose.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: I guess it depends on context. If you're working with functions every day, you start to use shorthand phrases. I use a variation (_"[input] yields [output]"_) **daily**, and I've never had a colleague ask me for clarification on what I just said.

Comment: @Flater well, yes, there's possibly a context in which anything anyone could say would make sense.  But this forum is supposed to be focused on the regular (non-context-specific) use of English, isn't it?    I think that most people would guess the intended meaning, anyway, I only said that it "feels wrong", by which I meant "I think it could be written more clearly".

Comment: I suggest most of those students would never have come up with that *alternative* independently, nor will be able to make a strong argument.
Then, a number can’t *give an answer* in the same way a door can’t *permit access* or a fingerprint *provide a clue*.
Asking *how can a number "give an answer”…* largely ensures it can't, and almost guarantees if it can, it won't be clear.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. Great discussion. Regarding the two meanings, I'm settling for @EdwinAshworth conclusion that the "alternative reading would always be conveyed differently".

Comment: Regarding whether a number can "give an answer", I will avoid it in my teaching for the reasons mentioned by @RobbieGoodwin. Although it might make sense in a maths question, it still seems a bit sloppy without a specific reference to a function.